# How can I permanently disable breakpoints in VS Code so they don't appear at all?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, breakpoints

I have been using VSCode for a long time and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Please don't confuse what I am asking with removing a break-point after I have added it. I simply want to disable them all together.

###### Here is an image of the break-points that I am referencing:

[image]

Comment: You can remove them by clicking on them again. Or right click -> remove breakpoint.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints

Comment: I asked how to remove them overall

Comment: There called breakpoints and if your writing a debuggable programming language the best solution is to learn what they are and how to use them, however, if you insist on disabling them, I have included an answer that "removes them overall" below, but you will have to disable the debugger (or debuggers) that are contributing them.

Comment: in the BREAKPOINTS view is a button to remove them all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```json
// Controls whether the editor should render the vertical glyph margin.
// The Glyph margin is mainly used for debugging.
"editor.glyphMargin": false
```

Paste the above setting into your VSCode `settings.json`.

Alternatively, go to the visual settings editor and search "glyph margin", which should take you to this section:

[image: Relevant setting in the UI]

Disable this setting.

Comment: This should be the approved comment, it is exactly what is being asked in the easiest method possible!

Answer (score 2):

Break-points are contributed by debugging extensions. If you want to rid your self of them you need to disable the debuggers for the markdown/programming language that your coding in.

First you need to check the extensions you installed for any debuggers. I included an image below that shows how to search for them.

[image]

Right click on the debugger extensions and disable them.

##### Now you need to look for debuggers built-in to VS Code

To do this, refer to the next image below.

[image]

and again, right click them, then disable them.

#### Additional Info:

Not every debugger is going to contribute breakpoints to the language your coding in. Its likely going to be a single debugging extension that contributes the breakpoints. Disabling all debuggers will get rid of them, but I suggest that after you get rid of the break points that you go back and enable the debuggers one by one, and check and see if the break-points come back after each one is disabled. This way you can find the debugger that is contributing them. Then disable only the debugger that is adding them, and leaving all other extensions enabled, as some features rely on them.
It looks like your writing a markup language, specifically either standard HTML, or XML (probably SVG). Those are not debuggable languages, so some extension is probably needlessly contributing breakpoints. Which means it might be a debugger you installed.

---

EDIT:

As an FYI, you should also make sure the setting *`"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere"`* is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, when the debugger is running, the 'Run and debug' view should be showing - and one pane there is the 'Breakpoints' view that lists all current breakpoints and their state. (if it's are not showing, check that the 'breakpoints' view is checked from the top 'Run and debug' menu).

In the Breakpoints view, are 3 icons:

- add new breakpoint ( + )
- toggle ALL breakpoints on or off (what the OP is asking for) (two on/off dots)
- remove all breakpoints (two stacked checkboxes)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

go click on the run part on tab and select remove all breakpoints

Comment: i bet you already got the answer but just in case fyi - breakpoints are part of a debugging feature that allows coders to interpret depending on certain lines for example if there's an error you can use breakpoint to check the certain code for mistake to prevent errors during compilation